# Uncaught ReferenceError: iscdnenabled is not defined(zone.js:423)

Tags: javascript, angular, zone

misunderstood bug in the application console on the Angular 7
[image]

`````
zone.js:199 Uncaught ReferenceError: iscdnenabled is not defined
    at Object.getFiles (floatbutton.js:1)
    at Object.populateIframe (floatbutton.js:1)
    at floatbutton.js:1
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:498)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
    at timer (zone.js:2281)````
`````

Comment: zone.js:199 Uncaught ReferenceError: iscdnenabled is not defined
    at Object.getFiles (floatbutton.js:1)
    at Object.populateIframe (floatbutton.js:1)
    at floatbutton.js:1
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:498)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
    at timer (zone.js:2281)

Comment: What is `floatbutton.js`? Is it a dependence or your own code? And could you please post the code where the error occurs?

Comment: I found the problem here is the problem with live chat on the site.
https://dtzpfzv31buvf.cloudfront.net/Nov_25_2019_https/js/floatbutton.js